# XIAOMI Mi A1 LTE bands - User manual or website is right?

Tags: 4g, mi-a1

Situation:

Live in Spain, moving to Argentina. Buy a new Xiaomi MI A1, on the website it lists support to LTE B4 (main band in Argentina).

Get the phone, open the box which says GLOBAL Version, but user manual's LTE band support list does not say B4.

I ask XIAOMI, the reply is "ignore the manual" (see screenshot, in spanish but pretty clear)

Any way to know which info to rely on? I will send it back if it does not support B4.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As per GSM Arena Website: These are the [bands](https://www.gsmarena.com/xiaomi_mi_a1-8776.php#global) of Xiaomi Mi A1 Global Version.

2G bands    GSM 850 / 900 / 1800 / 1900 - SIM 1 & SIM 2

3G bands    HSDPA 850 / 900 / 1900 / 2100

4G bands    LTE band 1(2100), 3(1800), 5(850), 7(2600), 8(900), 20(800), 38(2600), 40(2300)

Also, with GSM Arena's [Network Coverage](https://www.gsmarena.com/network-bands.php3?sCountry=Argentina) section in Argentina says about these bands:

2G capabilities :GSM 850, GSM 1900

3G capabilities : UMTS 850, UMTS 1900

4G capabilities : LTE 700(28), LTE 1700(4), LTE 2100 (4).

**LTE 2100 is listed as Network coverage and Mi A1's band**